# Is it possible to add a question from an inlinekeyboardbutton using aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="IP1")
async def menular(call: CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.answer( """
Please send your send....

""",parse_mode="HTML",reply_markup = instapack1)
```

Comment: I'd suggest you [edit] your question to add a little more information about what you have done so far and where you are stuck -- i.e. a [mcve].  As it is your question is a little hard to understand.  See [ask] and also https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for tips on writing questions that are more likely to get answers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.